# AmazonS3Client over proxy in hadoop(oozie)

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, proxy, oozie

I'm trying to run a java code through oozie. The code was written for the non-proxy environment, but I'm trying to implement that in environment that requires proxy server setup. This is the error I get when I run the job.

```
2015-05-18 09:22:26,929 WARN com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Now that is expected behaviour since I need to pass that one through the proxy, however the problem is that that I do not see this connection to hit proxy. All is trying to directly to internet and is blocked on firewall.

I have setup the general proxy for all connection for all hadoop nodes (since they will all require it at some point) using `/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml` properties:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1024m -Dhttp.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|*.localdomain</value>
    <final>false</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1024m -Dhttp.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|*.localdomain</value>
    <final>false</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dhttp.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=1.1.1.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|*.localdomain</value>
<final>false</final>
</property>
```

However the connection is still going through directly to internet simply bypassing those settings. I have another job that makes successful call to external API over this proxy, so I know that this setup works, just do not know why it does not work with AmazonS3Client

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the S3 library that was delivered with the application. It did not support the proxy at all. So in my case there was no way to do it without correcting the code.